# Можно ли в цикле for() использовать eval() ? Или конструктор цикла for()

Tags: php, циклы, eval

День добрый. Интересует возможно ли как то генерировать цикл for? т.е. передавать ему действия из переменной. Примерно так

```
$a = '$i = 0; $i < 10; $i++';
for(eval($a))
{
    $b[] = $i;
}
var_dump($b);
```

и получить такой ответ

```
array(10) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(6) [7]=> int(7) [8]=> int(8) [9]=> int(9) }
```

знаю что не работает) но хотелось бы использовать примерно такую конструкцию. Подскажите возможно ли реализовать подобное?

Comment: @alexlz к сожалению нет. Большинство (используемых мной) выражений в цикле for() нельзя переделать под foreach

Comment: под конкретно указанную задачу хорошо подойдет [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

А в общем случае нужно сильно смотреть задачу. Возможно, изобретаете велосипед. Так что пишите подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот несколько вариантов реализации "подобного")

```
// 1
foreach (eval('return array(1, 2, 3, 4);') as $v)
  echo $v.'<br />';

// 2
@list($from, $max, $inc) = eval('return array(0, 10, 1);');
for ($i = $from; $i < $max; $i += $inc)
  echo $i.'<br />';

// 3
$i = -1;
while (eval('$i++; return $i < 10;')) {
  echo $i.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: первый вариант - это чудный индусокод.

Comment: @KoVadim не мы такие, вопрос такой) Мало ли, автор хочет в БД код хранить по кускам. Я давно уже без повода вопрос "зачем" не задаю, у самого периодически возникают смешные подзадачи, которые решаются либо индусским кодом, либо 3-мегабайтной платной библиотекой.

Comment: заметил, что если у меня и возникает подобная ситуация, то это говорит лишь о том, что:

 - либо я просто не все знаю о стандартной библиотеке выбранного языка
 - либо я неправильно решаю задачу

Comment: @KoVadim вероятно, вам повезло решать только решаемые задачи в условиях достаточности инструментов)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$head = '$i = 0; $i < 10; $i++';
$body= '$b[] = $i;';
$do_for = 'for(' . $head . '){' . $body . '}';
eval($do_for);
var_dump($b);

?>
```